# How do I calculated total current on each line with an even number of circuits (unbalanced)

Tags: current, three-phase

In the first example I was calculating  the current each line would see for the purpose of sizing wire. An EE told me my calculation was wrong and that phase A would see 74A not 64A.

I'm wondering what I am doing wrong.

The second example is a slightly different configuration which I would think would be more balanced.

[image: First Example]

[image: Second Example]

Comment: Because the phases are 120 degrees apart, there is a correction factor needed when you sum the currents between the phases.  This correction factor is (SqRt 3).  Have a look at your problem again and edit your question with what you come up with.  We'll guide you from there.

Comment: Note that we are *not* going to give you the answer.  You have to work it out yourself.  But we'll help you get there.

Comment: I'm not asking you to do it for me. Im asking for an explanation of how to do it so I can do it myself. I already know what the answer is I want to know how to get there.

Comment: @DwayneReid, can we simplify this and look at it like a "high leg delta" connected load. Resulting in Vll = 2 * Vln = 554V? The load impedances should be 15 ohms, resulting in I = (554V / 15 ohm) * 2 = 73.9A

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to this question was very simple after some digging. I am not sure why people refused to help.

AB = current from line A to line B

AC = current from line A to line C

BC = current from line B to line C

[image: Equation to Calc current on Line A]

[image: Equation to Calc current on Line B]

[image: Equation to Calc current on Line C]